# How to design tentacle massage machine?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, modern-age

I started to wonder about the possibility of a tentacle massage machine. To make the setting even more bizarre, it was intended to be a mass market home appliance. The tech level should be comparable to contemporary, with somewhat better electronics and data processing.

The thing that makes me wonder: is there on this tech level any practical way of inexpensively (and safely) designing such flexible tentacles? Inflatable? Some hydraulics?

**EDIT (clarification):** I mostly though about tentacles in style of gigant octopus. Assuming however, that someone thinks that this size is unfeasible, unpractical or too expensive for mass market then solution for mind flayer or tiny squid are also fine.

**EDIT 2:** People who think its an offtopic please clarify your reasoning. The setting is intended to be original but disturbing on many levels (not a planet of hats), while still NOT being a hard line dystopia. How should I ask questions for that?

**EDIT 3:** I mean a machine that massages human beings by using some kind of mechanical tentacles.

Comment: I've seen enough to know where this is going...

Comment: Can you say more about the tentacles?  I imagine the approach would be different for a giant octopus, a mind flayer, and a tiny squid.

Comment: Technically this isn't really off topic...use downvotes if you don't like a question.

Comment: Are we talking about a massage machine that *has* tentacles, or a machine *for* massaging tentacles? Because squid need massages too, after all...

Comment: "How to build a machine that modern-feasible" is a mechanical engineering question, not Worldbuilding.

Comment: @RonJohn I think that for real engineering it would neither be serious enough nor possibility of using data processing beyond contemporary tech would be reasonable.

Comment: @Shadow1024 mechanical devices have been "taking over" human jobs since the first water wheels and windmills started grinding grain.  Replacing masseurs with mechanical devices is **completely reasonable**.  In fact, I'd bet that some Japanese company has -- or is in the process of -- already developed one.  Secondly, what do you mean by "nor possibility of using data processing beyond contemporary tech would be reasonable"?

Comment: @RonJohn typo. I meant possibiity of use such.

Comment: @Shadow1024 to clarify: do you think that modern computers can't control massage tentacles?

Comment: @RonJohn what I understand on OP's comment on data processing is that he machine needs to be able to analyse the physiology of the individual, and have knowledge of anatomy to know what kind of massage to apply. Although it would be better if Shadow1024 can clarify.

Comment: @Theraot I'd have **never** deduced that...  :)  Anyway, such skills can be easily (for a roboticist who consults a physiologist) programmed into a computer.  In addition to the tentacles (@sphenning's "soft robotics" sounds interesting), you'd have a pressure-sensitive mat to determine how large the person is, and a thermal sensor to determine which muscles are tense.

Comment: I'm quite convinced that contemporary computers technically would be able to control that, but I see great error potential. I mean for example the machine massaging forehead, while the person suddenly moves and is being hit in eye. Making software in such machine idiot-resistant could be the biggest challenge, while I wanted to ask concerning those tentacles.

Comment: What counts as a quality massage?  Are we talking deep tissue where the tentacles really work your muscles, or could they just loosely slap your back?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7AFsk40NGE, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkPeF-sYQ-0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZ5W7LyyKL0. The last one is quite agile - skip to 1:20 to see it reacting quickly

Comment: Why would a machine that massaged humans by using some kind of mechanical tentacles be a problem, other than through cost… and even then, why not simply sell it to rich people?

I'm assuming that "tentacles" simply means "some kind of massage mechanism" not specifically tied to real-life "tentacles".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This totally depends on what kind of massage you're thinking of. Most deep massages require a considerable amount of pressure - some masseuses will use their elbows or even heels. To achieve *that* - and, by the way, such a machine will be able to exert *dangerous* amounts of pressure - you're going to need hydraulics.

Soft or "finger" massages can use memory-form metals, pneumatics ([here, for grips](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/octopus-robot-tentacle)), or coil-and-wire setups (also called "spider motion" because this is how most arachnids' legs work; they're naturally bent, and the critter has to strain to distend them; the opposite of how human limbs work).

Then you have an additional form of massage which is not really feasible for humans: a tentacle can extert a considerable striction or compressive force, which may turn useful as a sort of lymphatic drainage massage on steroids.

However powered, your tentacles would probably end up being composed of a series of short, rigid sections with one, possibly two degrees of freedom each, one to "flex/bend" and one to (slightly) rotate. The last two or three sections on the tip could also be equipped with a piston (i.e. the tentacle tip can stretch forward), adding a third degree of freedom.

One thing the massaging tentacles would surely need is a biocompatible, sturdy silicon skin. Optionally they might need heating for comfort, and for special purposes the capability of delivering [electrical currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_muscle_stimulation). Support for vibration could also be a plus.

The tentacles would require some way of analyzing the part being massaged (if only to be sure they're not accidentally kneading your [carotid sinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czermak-Hering_test)). The best way would probably be via ultrasound (as @AndyD273 observed, this would recommend coating the imaging tentacles with ultrasound gel, i.e. slime. That might be a plus or a minus depending on the scenario).

For approaching the part, some kind of camera would be needed. The capability of such a camera to "see" into the infrared could also turn out to be useful as it would allow to estimate blood flow.

In case someone wanted to implement *specially purposed* tentacles (the scientific term would be [*hectocotyli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hectocotylus)) little would need to be done except modifying the controlling software; there could even be a black market of creative mods.

Comment: Another benefit of equipping your tentacles with ultrasound is that ultrasound can be used for deep tissue massage, which could lessen the amount of pneumatics needed. The tentacles would need to be coated in gel to facilitate the transmission of the ultrasound waves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therapeutic_ultrasound

Comment: @AndyD273 So effectively the tentacles should look like in an Alien movie because of being covered with mucus? Thanks, that clearly improves this setting. :D

Comment: @Shadow1024 Exactly! But more importantly, it's functional, and not just because tentacles really should be slimy... ;)

Answer (score 28):

I'd look into [soft robotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_robotics). This is a branch of robotics without hard components like motors or rigid structure. Tentacle like appendages are a common project among engineers working on the technology.

Most of the work being done now involves a soft latex form with multiple voids inside of it. Changing the pressure differential between voids will inflate some and contract others leading to a bending motion.

Comment: My thought exactly!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting in to looking in to soft robotics, if I could I'd accept also this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're going for bizarre, here's an idea:

Imagine a reclining chair with a fluid-filled sac attached to the back. This sac contains either bio-harvested octopus appendages or an actual Octopus which is preserved in a formaldehyde-like liquid.

An electric current is applied to the Octopus/appendages to make the tentacles move about in a rhythmic fashion. The person sitting on the chair feels this through the seat.

You can add minor details about how the tentacles are held upright and outstretched via attachments so that the entire assembly doesn't move around and out of position. The bag can either be solid black, transparent, or semi-transparent which shows the animal inside.

Comment: You promised bizarre, and bizarre is what you suggested... I have some doubt wether or not this should be considered an answer, but since i like it, have a +1 :-)

Comment: Maybe you could have octopus arms grown from stem cells, and then control them with implanted electric wires...